# Undefined property: PDOStatement::$rows

Tags: php, pdo, mysql-error-1064

I'm not sure why this bit of code:

```
if($sth->rows == 0){
    echo "Incorrect username or password - 1";
}
```

is pulling the error Undefined property: PDOStatement::$rows. This works just fine on a different PHP script that I basically had changed only a few things. I do however also receive the echo "Incorrect username or password -1" meaning that if statement did run.

Here is the full PHP code.

```
<?php
$lusername = $_POST['username'];
$lpassword = $_POST['password'];

//Hashing password
$cost = 10;

$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');

$salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;

$hash = crypt($lpassword, $salt);

// Create connection
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=weblupne_template3;host=localhost';
$username = 'somethingFreakingCrazyMagical';
$password = 'somethingEvenMoreCrazyFreakingMagical';
try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); // also allows an extra parameter of configuration
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // set the PDO error mode to exception
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('Could not connect to the database:<br/>' . $e);
}

//Where to select from
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT password FROM login WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1');
$sth->bindParam(':username', $lusername);
$sth->execute();
$user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if($sth->rows == 0){
    echo "Incorrect username or password - 1";
}
else{
    //Tests if correct
    echo $user->hash;
    if ( hash_equals($user->password, crypt($lpassword, $user->password)) ) {
        echo "You check out";
    }
    else{
        echo "Incorrect username or password - 2";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: perhaps the query execution failed, you dont check, you just assume.

Comment: I put the execution part in a try and catch statement and received no exception.

Comment: no your connection is in a try\catch not the select querry

Comment: Right I understand but I'm saying I just tried putting everything in that try catch statement and received the same feedback

Comment: ok, sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: [You don't need a row count](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count) as you have `$user` already. Just make it `if(!$user){` - that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$sth->rowCount()`, there is no property named `rows`.

Comment: This worked flawlessly. I'm confused as to why ->row works on my other php page though.